# take a string as an input from the key of dictionary and return all the values in alphabetical order in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

This function should take the first character from the key of a dictionary and return back all the keys in alphabetical order start with that first character without importing any files, when the method is:

```
def get_names_start(self,first_char,tools = None)
```

the dict looks like:

```
dict= {'Football' : 'BALL', 'Cricket' : 'BAT', 'Chess': 'CHESSBOARD'}
```

the output should be :

if we search by "C"

```
'Chess'

'Cricket'
```

Comment: Using `dict` as a variable name is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'Football': 'BALL', 'Cricket': 'BAT', 'Chess': 'CHESSBOARD'}
sorted([v for v in d if v.startswith("C")])
# => ['Chess', 'Cricket']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one attempt

```
def f(ch="C"):
    d= {'Football' : 'BALL', 'Cricket' : 'BAT', 'Chess': 'CHESSBOARD'}
    ll = list()
    for k in d:
        if k[0] == ch:
            ll.append(k)
    return sorted(ll)

print f("C")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
di= {'Football' : 'BALL', 'Cricket' : 'BAT', 'Chess': 'CHESSBOARD'}

def f(d,k):
    return sorted( [ x for x in d.keys() if x.lower().startswith(k.lower())])

print(f(di,'c'))

['Chess', 'Cricket']
```